# read data from keyboard without newline

Tags: bash, console, newline

I have a task that forces users to enter right data, for example

```
echo -e "Enter digit (choices: 2, 3, 4, 5)\c"
tput sc
read -p ": " DIGIT

while ! [[ ${DIGIT:0:1} =~ ^[[:digit:]]$ ]]; do
    tput rc; tput cuu1
    echo -e " [incorrect, try again or CTRL-C for exit]\c"
    read -p ": " DIGIT
done
```

this works the way I need it except one, if user inputs incorrect value - not a digit then empty line appears on the bottom.

```
$ ./i.sh
Enter digit (choices: 2, 3, 4, 5) [incorrect, try again or CTRL-C for exit]:
{empty line here}
```

Is it possible the input string always stayed on a row and did not jumped up?

UPDATE: User's input can be any length in the working version, accordingly

and regex for testing can be any too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-n` flag of `read` which lets you receive a single character from the user, without them needing to type <kbd>Enter</kbd> and jumping to the next line.

```
echo -e "Enter digit (choices: 2, 3, 4, 5)\c"
tput sc

while true; do
    read -n 1 -p ": " DIGIT
    if [[ ${DIGIT:0:1} =~ ^[[:digit:]]$ ]]; then
        break
    fi
    tput rc;
    echo -e " [incorrect, try again or CTRL-C for exit]\c"
done

echo
```

Comment: One character of user input is particular case. Users can input a string of any length also regex can be any.